# Custom font could be read with jdk 8, but not with jdk 11

Tags: java, fonts, embedded-resource

This is my code:

```java
public static Font getFont() {
        try {
            InputStream is = Object.class.getResourceAsStream("/HARCOMAS.TTF");
            return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StartPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The version on my computer is jdk 8 and the program works, however, when I copied the program to my friends computer with jdk 11, an exception occurred.

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
 at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1183)
 at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1052)
 at client.utils.PanelUtil.getFont(PanelUtil.java:39)
 at client.services.DrawGame.<init>(DrawGame.java:24)
 at client.views.GamePanel.createPanel(GamePanel.java:31)
 at client.views.GamePanel.<init>(GamePanel.java:24)
 at client.views.PanelHolder.<clinit>(PanelHolder.java:12)
 at client.views.MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:29)
```

I have no idea, and the font file is under the resource directory.

Comment: Did you use tomcat

Comment: @Kalana No I am using java swing

Comment: Did you also copy and paste that .ttf file to your expected directry

Comment: Try to load font file from file system using FileInputStream

Comment: `"/HARCOMAS.TTF"` 1) The resource name is really all upper case? 2) Are you sure the font is in the **root** of the Jar? 2) What does this have to do with Swing?

Comment: I copied the whole project with resource directory, and the filename is indeed upper case. The project is a game and I use it to customize the interface. What's more, I don't have a jar; I just copied the project folder.

Comment: Reminder: Add @AhsanShah (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. If you have further comments to me, please tag me. I'm closing this tab in the browser to make space.